# How do I send file with string to server in vuejs

Tags: arrays, json, vue.js, form-data

I am developing an app with vuejs(frontend) and laravel8(backend)

I want the user to upload the from his local computer

which I will send to laravel  server alongside string

I created array of sections and array of sub sections inside the sections

In the sub sections I have a file

when I tried to send the section array to the server which I converted to json the file becomes empty

Vuejs

```
export default {
  name: 'CreateCourse',
  setup(){
      const sections = reactive([{'section_title': '', 'sub_sections': [{'sub_section_title': '', 'file': '', 'url': ''}]}]);

      const course = reactive({'title': '', 'description': ''});
      const {showLoader} = magicFunction();
        const authUser = AuthService.data();
        const file = reactive({"file" :''})
       console.log('user id ', `${authUser.user.id}`);
       const formRules = computed(() => {
            return {
            title: {required},
            description: {
                required,
                minLength: minLength(20),
                },
            }
        });
        let v$ = useVuelidate(formRules, course);
        const addSection = () => {
            sections.push({"section_title": "", 'sub_sections': [{'sub_section_title': '', 'file': '', 'url': ''}]});
        }
        const addSubSection = (idx) => {
            console.log('the value of idx is ', idx);
            sections[idx].sub_sections.push({"sub_section_title": "", 'file': '', 'url': ''});
        }

        const uploadFile = (e, idx, i) => {

            sections[idx].sub_sections[i].file = e.target.files[0];
            file.file = e.target.files[0];
            sections[idx].sub_sections[i].url = URL.createObjectURL(sections[idx].sub_sections[i].file);
            
            console.log("no json", file.file);
            console.log("Object is file is ",JSON.stringify(file.file));

        }
        
        const createCourse = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
         if (v$.value.$invalid) {
          v$.value.$touch();
          return;
        }


        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("course", course.title);
        formData.append("description", course.description);
        formData.append("sections",  JSON.stringify(sections));
        formData.append("user_id", `${authUser.user.id}`);
        formData.append("hub_id", `${authUser.hub.id}`);
    

        console.log("Object is file is ",JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(file.file)));
        console.log("file is ", file.file);
        showLoader(true);
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/courses', formData, {
            headers: {
            'accept': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        }).then(response => {
            NotificationService.success(response.data.message);
            showLoader(false);
            // course.title = '';
            // course.description = '';
        }).catch(err => {
            NotificationService.error(err.response);
            showLoader(false);
        });
      }

    return {
        course,
        createCourse,
        v$,   
        sections,
        addSection,
        addSubSection,
        uploadFile
    }
  }
```

How do I solve this problem?